# MQTT message publishing time

Tags: python, time

I have a MQTT program written in python where it publishes JSON messages on a loop. It looks something like this:

```
while True: 
  publish.single("sensor/data", json.dumps(JSONMessage), hostname = "test.mosquitto.org")
```

I want to **record** the time the first message is published. Also, I want to do this only **once**, so I don't want that time to be updated constantly in this loop.

**My two questions are:** Does there exist a python library that can log the time of the first message published? And how can I do it so that time isn't updated each time the loop runs? Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I've looked at the python library Moment, but I didn't see a why to log exactly when the message is published (since there could be a delay).

Comment: Ignore libraries, think basic `if` statements